# gen_salt postgresql pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I'm studying pgcrypto and I'm interested in:

```
(crypt('123@', gen_salt('bf', 4)))
```

I can get a boolean value if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = crypt('123@', password)
```

But if I want to decrypt the amount I entered in my bank? how do I do ?
I saw that we have the `pgp_sym_encrypt()` function

but this function needs a `'secret-key'` to decrypt, I didn't find it that interesting
Is there a way to decrypt something that was generated by `gen_salt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following code to encrypt and decrypt your data securely by using postgres pgcrypto extension;

```
-- Encrypting data using pgp_sym_encrypt
INSERT INTO encrypted_data (encrypted_amount) VALUES (pgp_sym_encrypt('1000', 'secret_key'));

-- Decrypting data using pgp_sym_decrypt
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(encrypted_amount, 'secret_key') FROM encrypted_data;
```

Hope it works :)